# How many ways are there to choose k from n such that the longest consecutive block chosen is j things long?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, recursive-algorithms, constraints

> Denote the number of $\binom{n}{k}$ such that the longest consecutive block of things chosen is exactly $j$ things long as ${\binom{n}{k}}_{j}$, where $j\leq k \leq n$; the goal is to derive a general or (more likely) recursive formula.

For $j=0$, notice ${\binom{n}{k}}_{0}=1$ when $k=0$ and ${\binom{n}{k}}_{0}=0$ when $k>0$.

For $j=1$, ${\binom{n}{k}}_{1} \quad (k>0) \quad $ is equivalent to the number of ways to choose where none are consecutive, which is given by the well known formula $\binom{n+1-k}{k}$. Rewrite 
$$\binom{n+1-k}{k} = \binom{n-k}{k-1} + \binom{n-k}{k} = \binom{(n-2)+1-(k-1)}{(k-1)} + \binom{(n-1)+1-(k)}{(k)}$$ 
using Vandermonde's Identity, and recursion is established for $j=1$ $(k>1)$:
$$\binom{n}{k}_1 = \binom{n-2}{k-1}_1 + \binom{n-1}{k}_1$$
However, this does not hold for $j\geq2$ and I'm stuck. It feels intuitive that a recursive method should exist.

Comment: Do you allow a recurrence in $j$ itself too? If so, can you pick consecutive blocks of length $j$ and then go down with $j$?

Comment: yes, any of n, k, j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a recursive formula by conditioning on the first block (the element 1 does not appear, or 1 appears in a block of length $r<j$, or 1 appears in a block of length $j$):
$$\binom{n}{k}_j=\binom{n-1}{k}_j+\sum_{r=1}^{j-1} \binom{n-r-1}{k-r}_j+\sum_{s=0}^j\binom{n-j-[j<n]}{k-j}_s$$